# Proguard for Android/gradle: obfuscation, renaming BroadcastReceiver and activities referenced in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, proguard

I'm trying to get my BroadcastReceiver renamed, as it's the only one class which shows up under original package name, all others are renamed with `-repackageclasses`

```
##-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
```

From a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424391/proguard-obfuscating-does-not-work):

> "Some classes can't be obfuscated because their names are specified in the AndroidManifest.xml (e.g. activities)."

So, it seems to be possible with DexGuard, and of course some manual (scripted) renaming/editing is possible.. but are there any possibilities for vanilla Proguard + gradle to deal with manifests?

Comment: I think if you don't use AndroidManifest but register boradcast receiver in code than if you don't have anything in proguard configuration it will be obfuscated. But there might be drawbacks in code registration approach like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876015/broadcast-receiver-register-in-manifest-vs-activity

Comment: Can you give idea why do you want to obfuscate name of receiver since it is still will extend android reiver and it will be hard to hide it

Comment: @EugenMartynov preventing reverse engineering in a crude way.. having packages with obvious name "org.company.dataframework" will give some hints which I'd like to avoid providing.

Comment: Clear, but it is still quite easy to find Broadcast Receiver